# Macbook Pro 2014 Retina with Yosemite (Remove all Mac OS x and Install Windows 8.1 Pro or Mac OS X again if possible)

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, apple-id

Me and my ex-girlfriend purchased a macbook pro last year, This is the new 13inch MBP with retina display and has no cd drive. I have never used a macbook pro other than to surf the internet. We recently went through a brake up and due to me purchasing the macbook originally we agreed i could take this, She was not happy that i took the MBP however it is by rights mine and therefore had no grounds to keep this from me. However to be as bitter as possible she decided to block me from using the icloud and itunes account and because my knowledge with MBP is very restricted i have no idea what i am doing to reinstall everything fresh.

I went into Disk utils and formatted the Macintosh HD however when i try to reinstall Yosemite from the Recovery Partition it asks for her Login ID and that i no longer have as she changed the password.

Is it possible to totally delete everything from the SSD including recovery partion and either install windows 8.1 pro i bought on disk as i have put this onto USB now, Or could i reinstall Mac OS X again fresh.

To do this i need to format the recovery partition so it removes her Apple ID, She was the most advanced out of us both with mac's and was her who persuaded me to purchase this.

I just want my beloved computer back to normality, i much prefer windows and if possible i would like to 100% Totally format the SSD Clean and start a windows installation from scratch so she can not cause me any more hassle.

She told me she would block my MBP with find my mac if i try and login with her apple id, There is no reason for her to be so evil and i want her ID removed totally and any files she has on my laptop.

I really am no good with macs however i understand how to follow instructions and would be extremely grateful for any help and advice given, She lives in the same State as me and use to go to the same university as me so i copied her university files onto USB and give her these but she still wants to be evil.

Comment: If you have the original proof of purchase go to Apple Store and they will fix it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been researching the topic for a while, and with success, I have created a bootable USB. If you still have any access to the mac, you should be able to do the same thing I did. Open the App Store, then click "Store" in the menu. click on the button that says sign out.

Press sign in, then create a new Apple ID (it's free. say you don't have any payment info.) you will get a confirmation email. confirm your email, then proceed to the App Store and sign in. go to the following page https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/os-x-yosemite/id915041082?mt=12

While this is downloading, open a tab in safari and download the following assistant from Disk Maker. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/118949/downloads/DiskMakerX4b4.dmg

Find a USB stick (that is or is over 8GB) that you don't mind formatting, then wait for Yosemite to finish downloading. When it is done, open DiskMakerX4b4.dmg and open the App inside. It should ask you what disk you want to install the OS X installer to. Find the drive, then click choose. This will launch the installer, then put a recovery HD onto a USB. It will not ask for your ex's password. This may take up to (but not limited to) an hour.

When your computer is done this process, shut it down, then use the following key: option then click on the drive that says "Install OS X Yosemite"

Once your mac has booted onto the drive, click the Disk Utility, then go to Partition. Click 1 partition, then name it Macintosh HD. Press apply or create. (it will be under the naming of the Partition)

Go back to the main menu, then click reinstall OS X. This will take around an hour.

This has been adapted from the following articles:

http://www.maclife.com/article/howtos/ask_how_reinstall_os_x_without_dvd

http://diskmakerx.com

http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/create-mac-flash-recovery-drive-for-emergencies-3499802/

http://osxdaily.com/2014/10/18/clean-install-os-x-yosemite/

Best of luck,

Comment: Hi Bret, Do you have an email address.. Skype or any way of means i could contact you please? i greatly appreciate your help and advice and i will be following this up. However i have formatted the Macintosh HD following a dead end youtube video at first port of call before i come to Stack Exchange for help, However i have since installed Yosemite on a normal windows laptop i have in VM Ware so i am hoping to do the same steps from a virtual machine and save everything required to a USB stick i have that is 64gb and use that on my macbook pro.  Thanks

Comment: You can contact me at bret7600@gmail.com. And my name is Brett. @Jrad51

Answer (score 0):

You can (in addition to the above) hold down Command + Option + R to boot into Internet Recovery Mode. This will download and install the version of the operating system that shipped with the unit (likely Mavericks) and you can upgrade from there. Since this is using a factory-provided image and not the App Store upgrade, the account is not tied to it and the install will proceed without asking you for credentials.

For Find My Mac, your ex will have to remove the computer from her account. Otherwise the potential for her to lock it still exists.

Windows can also only be installed via Bootcamp or other (unsupported) methods, so you will generally have to have a copy of OSX on the computer no matter what. However, it does not need to be the primary OS you boot into nor the holder of all of the disk space.

Hope this helps!